# Closed End Waves

Tags: waves, acoustics

[image]

Why is phase difference between P and Q =**0**?

Comment: Is it so?  The phase difference could have been constant...

Comment: Yeah, that is trippin me atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $N$ points indicate nodes, so this is a standing wave situation. In a standing wave, all points are at the same phase. For example, when $P$ is at its maximum, so is $Q$.